# Find a Square matrix of order n meeting the condition: $I - A = A^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have been working on a problem: "Find a square matrix of order $n$ that meets the condition $I - A = A^{2}$" Where $I$ is the identity matrix.

$(R^{n\times n})$. I have tried working on a $3\times3$ matrix using the property $A \times A^{-1} = I$ and moving on from there but I think I have hit a wall and have become stuck.

Any help provided would be appreciated.

Comment: is $I$ a unit matrix$?$

Comment: @aaabbb Presumably the identity matrix

Comment: @aaabbb I is the identity matrix, sorry should have worded it better!

Comment: Don't worry @Visor450 everyyone knows $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: One always tries first the case $n=1$, so can you solve it in this case? How many answers are possible?

Comment: Matrix $aI_n$ fits your requirement, where $a = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: @Guangliang hello, did you first set the matrix as a series of equations and calculate each element?

Comment: @Visor450 I didn't actually solve the matrix equation.  I just found the solution $a$ for 1x1 matrix, then $aI_n$ fits your requirement.  I would imagine there are more solutions than this one.

Comment: @Guangliang & ancient mathematician, thank you I think I understand how to solve this problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Guangliang and A. Mathematician's help it is possible to note that we can solve this using a 1x1 matrix as our basis (1 = n), where it becomes an equation: $$1 - a = a^2$$, which when simplified gives us: $$a^2 + a - 1 = 0$$ with the result being: $\frac{1\pm \sqrt{5} }{2}$

Comment: The conclusion is missing. You should add that what you wrote implies that the matrices $A = aI$ is an example  of a square matrix such that $I-A = A^2$.

Comment: The companion matrix of $t^2+t-1$ is the required matrix.